# codeigniter 2.1.3 strange issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have codeigniter webservice for my android application. Basically I do not know php coding but can do host etc. I am using this from last 2 years. It was working fine before 2 days. Now I am facing issue like below

***Some time some page which I have linked on welcome page called is not opening. when I click on button for open linked page...its just refreshing dashboard....some time when I click on pagination number its going to dashboard page instead of load next...previous page. If I clear my cache from browser...and try to load all page...its working smooth...some time not..***

Can anybody please help me for solve the issue ? Its virus or cache issue ?

Comment: Codeigniter 2.x is no longer supported. There have been hundreds of bug fixes, improvements and security improvements in CI 3.x which has been out for quite some time now. It sounds like you have a session issue and some of your user page position within the site is being stored in your sessions. You really should upgrade to 3.x since 2.x branch is irrecoverably broken. The 3.x branch had the session libraries completely re-written.

Comment: Unless you meant CI 3.1.2 in which case try upgrading to CI 3.1.3 as there were a few Session bug fixes in the change log.